# Difference between access token from Graph Explorer API Tool and Access Token Debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am studying Facebook API. From "Graph API Explorer", I got one access token. From the "Access token debugger" , I got two access tokens. But what is the difference between these tokens?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get two access tokens from the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/), you can only debug one token at a time. You probably mean the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) which gives a user access token and an application access token. The difference was described at the top

> The user tokens listed here are provided for convenience to test your apps. They expire like any other user access token and should not be hard coded into your apps. App tokens do not expire and should be kept secret as they are related to your app secret. For more information on how access tokens work and should be used, see the documentation.